# C++ File to Vector

Tags: c++, file, object, vector

I've got a file that looks like this:

```
C 0484758654 95
C 0428473483 121
T 0494569848
C 0494569848 121
//.. 30 or so more entries
```

I want to store each "person" (represented by their phone number) into an object. I know I'll need a structure to store this in so I used a Vector:

```
 using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("test.txt");
        vector<MonthlyPhoneBill> bill;
        MonthlyPhoneBill temp;
        while (fin >> temp.code>> temp.phoneNumber >> temp.data)
            {
                bill.push_back(temp);
            }

        for (const auto& temp : bill) {
        cout << temp.code << ' ' << temp.phoneNumber << ' ' << temp.data << endl;
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Class:

```
class MonthlyPhoneBill {

public:
    MonthlyPhoneBill();
    int data;
    int phoneNumber;
    std::string code;
    int totalBill;
};
```

I have a couple of problems however, the first problem is when I'm printing the file contents out it only prints the first line.

My second problem is that I have no idea how to manipulate the data now that it's stored in the vector. For example I'm wanting to calculate a bill for each individual person. I'm not sure how to access the contents of the vector and do calculations accordingly. From the file an individual person could come up multiple times and I'm not sure how to add the total cost each time they were to come up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code only prints the first two lines, and not the first line in the file. Keep looking at the file, and try to figure out what's different about the third line, then remember this motto: "a computer does only what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do". After remembering this motto, ask yourself: what did you tell your computer to do, in terms of reading each line? Now, as far as accessing the contents of the vector, this is explained fully in your C++ book. Is there something specific in your C++ book that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sam Varshavchik said, look what's different about the third line, because indeed it is different - it's missing the last value, the `data` member. This causes the `while` to exit as it encounters no data when executing the last part of `while (fin >> temp.code>> temp.phoneNumber >> temp.data)`, i.e. the `>> temp.data`.

As for the second question, again like @Sam Varshvchik said - consult your C++ book. You can manipulate the vector of your class entries in any operation, just like you did when printing contents.

To compute the total bill for each person seems to me that your program would need to undergo some changes. Since your users are repeated in the main vector, one way would be to iterate through it and group the repetitions into a single class object per user with summed bills. The other way would be to sort the main vector by phone numbers, i.e. users. Once sorted you could use approaches similar to ones in Chapter 7 of [Lippman's C++ Primer](https://books.google.com/books/about/C++_Primer.html?id=J1HMLyxqJfgC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MonthPhoneBill {
    int data;
    int phoneNumber;
    std::string code;
    int totalBill;
};

int main () {
    std::vector<MonthPhoneBill> dataEntry;
    ....
    ....
    MonthPhoneBill temp;
    // After Putting data into vector, one can simply access the data by.
    while (fin >> temp.code>> temp.phoneNumber >> temp.data >> temp.totalBill) {
            bill.push_back(temp);
   }
```

Please keep in mind the content of file should be also in that format like in `while` loop and you have to stream all the content of that structure. you cannot miss it, if happened all the other entry will be garbage or could lead to code crash

```
auto temp0 = dataEntry[1].data;
auto temp1 = dataEntry[1].phoneNumber;
auto temp2 = dataEntry[1].code;
   ....
}
```

you can simply manipulate the data and access it.